# Is it possible for a visitor in c++ to operate over multiple projects?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to add a visitor to an existing library. The visitor must be able to visit some classes from separate projects.

Let's say my solution have the following projects: `ProjectA`, `ProjectB` and they contain 1 class each respectively: `NodeA`, `NodeB`. Since the visitor is only an implementation of a class member outside of the class, I think its dependency won't allow it to be placed at another project. So if I want to create a visitor which can visit both `NodeA` and `NodeB` objects, I can't use a simple visitor.

Is this assessment correct?

I was thinking about a couple of solutions to overcome this.

1. Move one of the classes to the other projectand implement visitor there (this isnot a feasible solution).
2. Add an extra indirection. Create a class for the visitor implementation for each project. And create a "head visitor" which would use these implementation objects.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Please find my visitor implementation below. Please note that I removed header guards for the sake of simplicity.

```cpp
/// --- Node.h in project A ---
class Visitor;

class Node {
  public:
    Node() = default;
    virtual ~Node() = default;
    virtual void accept(Visitor & v) = 0;
};

/// --- NodeA.h  in project A ---
#include "Visitor.h"

class NodeA : public Node {
public:
    void accept(Visitor & v);
};

/// --- NodeB.h  in project B ---
#include "Visitor.h"

class NodeB : public Node {
public:
    void accept(Visitor & v);
};

/// --- Visitor.h ---
#include "Node.h"

class NodeA;
class NodeB;

class Visitor {
  public:
    Visitor() = default;
    virtual ~Visitor() = default;

    virtual void visit(const Node & node);
    virtual void visit(const NodeA & node);
    virtual void visit(const NodeB & node);
};

// --- Visitor.cpp ---

#include "Visitor.h"
#include "NodeA.h"

void Visitor::visit(const Node & node)
{
   // implementation
}

void Visitor::visit(const NodeA & node)
{
   // implementation
}

void Visitor::visit(const NodeB & node)
{
   // implementation
}
```

Comment: Please show your visitor implementation.

Comment: Added with edit

Comment: What is `B.hpp` and `C.hpp` here? Does `ProjectB` also include `Node.h`?

Comment: That's a renaming issue. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If I put a visitor interface class to the same project as Node and only use that in the derived node headers, I can put the derived Visitor classes to different projects, which will depend on everything (base and derived nodes and base visitor). The visit method will be dynamically dispached to the appropriate visitor  instance.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing in common between `NodeA` and `NodeB` other than being able to accept a visitor and store it in a, say, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` consider using `std::variant` instead.

The code looks something like this:

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class NodeA {};
class NodeB {};

using Node = std::variant<NodeA, NodeB>;



class Visitor
{
public:
  void operator()(NodeA & node) 
  {
    std::cout << "encountered A" << std::endl;
  }
  
  void operator()(NodeB & node) 
  {
    std::cout << "encountered B" << std::endl;
  }
};



int main() 
{
  std::vector<Node> nodes;
  nodes.emplace_back(NodeA{});
  nodes.emplace_back(NodeA{});
  nodes.emplace_back(NodeB{});
  nodes.emplace_back(NodeA{});
  nodes.emplace_back(NodeB{});
  nodes.emplace_back(NodeB{});
  
  Visitor visitor;
  
  for (auto & node : nodes)
  {
    std::visit(visitor, node);
  }
}
```

This way the implementation of `NodeA`, `NodeB` and the visitor is mostly decoupled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) Athough I don;t see ho it would solve the issue that the dependency between the project of the Visitor and the project of the Visitee are not the same thus resulting in circular dependency/reference between the projects.

Comment: You cannot escape the fact that your visitor has to know all possible types it could visit.

Comment: Yes, my thoughts exactly. My question is regarding what would be a good solution to overcome this. I pointed out 2 ways to deal with it, but non of them are particularily to my liking.